# Where can I find cinterop tool to create def file?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm trying to use SocketRocket Objective-C library on my Kotlin MPP project and I need to import it using cinterop, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

There is Kotlin Multiplatform Gradle plugin. The plugin delivers the `cinterop` tool for you. You may find more documentation here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#cinterop-support

You may also follow one of (to be updated) tutorials for Kotlin/Native with the explanation on how to find the `conterop` tool
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/interop-with-c.html